# Vue Formulate - Testing event emission on form button click using testing-library

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-formulate, vue-testing-library

I have the following component, using [Vue Formulate](https://vueformulate.com/)

```js
<template>
  <FormulateForm @submit="onSubmit">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </FormulateForm>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Issue',
  methods: {
    onSubmit(): void {
      this.$emit('my-special-event')
    },
  },
})
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

My goal is to test that, when I click the "Submit" button, `my-special-event` event is emitted. And I need to do this using [testing-library](https://testing-library.com/). Here's my attempt:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueFormulate from '@braid/vue-formulate'
import Issue from '~/components/Issue.vue'

describe('Issue component', () => {
  it('test', async () => {
    Vue.use(VueFormulate)
    const component = render(Issue)

    const submitBtn = component.getByText('Submit')
    await fireEvent.click(submitBtn)

    expect(component.emitted()).not.toEqual({})
  })
})
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work - no events are emitted. A similar test for a non-Formulate form works ok, though.

Comment: You probably need to `await nextTick()` or flush promises after the button click before you check for emission

Comment: @jpschroeder, adding `await new Promise(process.nextTick)` seems to do the trick. Want to add an answer, so that you get the credit? :)